# how could i optimise this python loop?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, for-loop

I am running this code on a large csv file (1.5 million rows). Is there a way to optimise ?

df is a pandas dataframe.
I take a row and want to know what happens 1st in the 1000 folowing rows :

I find my value + 0.0004 or i find my value - 0.0004

```
result = []
for row in range(len(df)-1000):
    start = df.get_value(row,'A')
    win = start + 0.0004
    lose = start - 0.0004
    for n in range(1000):
        ref = df.get_value(row + n,'B')
        if ref > win:
            result.append(1)
            break
        elif ref <= lose:
            result.append(-1)
            break
        elif n==999 :
            result.append(0)
```

the dataframe is like :

```
         timestamp           A         B
0   20190401 00:00:00.127  1.12230  1.12236
1   20190401 00:00:00.395  1.12230  1.12237
2   20190401 00:00:00.533  1.12229  1.12234
3   20190401 00:00:00.631  1.12228  1.12233
4   20190401 00:00:01.019  1.12230  1.12234
5   20190401 00:00:01.169  1.12231  1.12236
```

the result is : result[0,0,1,0,0,1,-1,1,…]

this is working but takes a long time to process on such large files.

Comment: Can you share expected output?

Comment: Please post a sample dataframe along with your desired output.

Comment: @Cleb : I added a sample dataframe, the output is a list with 1, -1 or 0 values.

Comment: so if B is more than `0.004` than A then you want to add 1 to a list, if its less than `0.004` then -1 else 0?

Comment: @Datanovice : 
I take the value A of a given row, and whant to know witch case happen first in the 1000 following rows :  
    - I found a value in B > A+0.0004 => I return 1  
    - Or I found a value in B <= A-0.0004 => I return -1  
    - I found nothing in 1000 rows (A-0.0004 < B < A+0.0004) => I return 0

Comment: @Datanovice  the point is to find witch case happen first in the following rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate values for the "first outlier", define the following function:

```
def firstOutlier(row, dltRow = 4, dltVal = 0.1):
    ''' Find the value for the first "outlier". Parameters:
    row    - the current row
    dltRow - number of rows to check, starting from the current
    dltVal - delta in value of "B", compared to "A" in the current row
    '''
    rowInd = row.name                        # Index of the current row
    df2 = df.iloc[rowInd : rowInd + dltRow]  # "dltRow" rows from the current
    outliers = df2[abs(df2.B - row.A) >= dlt]
    if outliers.index.size == 0:  # No outliers within the range of rows
        return 0
    return int(np.sign(outliers.iloc[0].B - row.A))
```

Then apply it to each row:

```
df.apply(firstOutlier, axis=1)
```

This function relies on the fact that the DataFrame has the index consisting
of consecutive numbers, starting from 0, so that having *ind* - the index of
any row we can access it calling `df.iloc[ind]` and a slice of *n* rows,
starting from this row, calling `df.iloc[ind : ind + n]`.

For my test, I set the default values of parameters to:

- `dltRow = 4` - look at **4** rows, starting from the current one,
- `dltVal = 0.1` - look for rows with **B** column "distant by" **0.1**
  or more from **A** in the current row.

My test DataFrame was:

```
      A     B
0  1.00  1.00
1  0.99  1.00
2  1.00  0.80
3  1.00  1.05
4  1.00  1.20
5  1.00  1.00
6  1.00  0.80
7  1.00  1.00
8  1.00  1.00
```

The result (for my data and default values of parameters) was:

```
0   -1
1   -1
2   -1
3    1
4    1
5   -1
6   -1
7    0
8    0
dtype: int64
```

For your needs, change default values of params to *1000* and *0.0004* respectively.

Comment: I think you must change dlt for dltVal in "outliers = df2[abs(df2.B - row.A) >= dlt]".
Thanks you, i'am testing your solution.

Comment: Thx, on 10 000 rows, your code takes 8.5 sec, mine was 78.2 sec, still takes a long time to process 1.5 millions rows but it's a great improvement !

Answer (score -1):

The idea is to loop through `A` and `B` while maintaining a sorted list of `A` values. Then, for each `B`, find the highest `A` that loses and the lowest `A` that wins. Since it's a sorted list it's `O(log(n))` to search. Only those `A`'s that have index in the last 1000 are used for setting the result vector. After that the `A`'s that are no longer waiting for a `B` are removed from this sorted list to keep it small.

```
import numpy as np
import bisect
import time

N = 10
M = 3
#N=int(1e6)
#M=int(1e3)
thresh = 0.4

A = np.random.rand(N)
B = np.random.rand(N)
result = np.zeros(N)

l = []

t_start = time.time()

for i in range(N):
    a = (A[i],i)
    bisect.insort(l,a)
    b = B[i]
    firstLoseInd = bisect.bisect_left(l,(b+thresh,-1))
    lastWinInd = bisect.bisect_right(l,(b-thresh,-1))
    for j in range(lastWinInd):
        curInd = l[j][1]
        if curInd > i-M:
            result[curInd] = 1
    for j in range(firstLoseInd,len(l)):
        curInd = l[j][1]
        if curInd > i-M:
            result[curInd] = -1
    del l[firstLoseInd:]
    del l[:lastWinInd]

t_done = time.time()

print(A)
print(B)
print(result)
print(t_done - t_start)
```

This is a sample output:

```
[ 0.22643589  0.96092354  0.30098532  0.15569044  0.88474775  0.25458535
  0.78248271  0.07530432  0.3460113   0.0785128 ]
[ 0.83610433  0.33384085  0.51055061  0.54209458  0.13556121  0.61257179
  0.51273686  0.54850825  0.24302884  0.68037965]
[ 1. -1.  0.  1. -1.  0. -1.  1.  0.  1.]
```

For `N = int(1e6)` and `M = int(1e3)` it took about 3.4 seconds on my computer.

Comment: probably not advisable to use a for loop since we have vectorised solutions available. for loops are the last resort usually.